# How can I set max size for cdockablepane?

Tags: mfc

I'm using MFC.

I know that cdockablepane has 'setminsize' method.

so I can set minimum size.

but it doesn't have limit max size method like 'setmaxsize'.

I want to set limit max size for cdockablepane. (is this possible?)

Please give me Any Ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setborders`. You can pass either individual numbers or `CRect`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cpane-class#setborders